# ionic 3 item onload function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-content class="bg">
   <ion-list  >
     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of mesajlar" (click)="openmsg(item.kimeid)">
       <h2>{{item.kimeadi}}</h2>
       <p>{{sonmesaj}}</p>
       <ion-note item-end>{{sonmesajtarih}}</ion-note>
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

When I have clicked to item , calling function with params `item.kimeid`
and I want to call function with params `item.kimeid` when item is loading.

How can I do this?

```
mesajlar: Observable<any>;

sonmesaj: string = "";
sonmesajtarih: string = "";

kimeid: string = "";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams,
public http: Http,
public modalCtrl: ModalController,
) {
}

mesajiac(kimeid,kimeadi,kiminid,kiminadi){

const modal =  this.modalCtrl.create(MesajPage,{
  kimeid: kimeid,
  kimeadi: kimeadi,
  kiminid: kiminid,
  kiminadi: kiminadi

  });
  modal.present();
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  const rsuserid = localStorage.getItem("rsuserid");

  let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
  options: any = { key: "kontrol", rsuserid: rsuserid },
  url: any = "http://185.181.9.84/RakipSizsiniz/php/mesajlarigetir.php";
  console.log(options);

  this.http
  .post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.mesajlar = res;

 });
}
 sonmesajigetir(){
  const rsuserid = localStorage.getItem("rsuserid");

  let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }),
  options: any = { key: "kontrol", kiminid: rsuserid, kimeid: this.kimeid},
  url: any = "http://185.181.9.84/RakipSizsiniz/php/sonmesajigetir.php";
  console.log(options);

  this.http
  .post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
   this.sonmesaj = res.sonmesaj;
   this.sonmesajtarih = res.tarih;
 });
}
```

I take `mesajlar` from database with php file, and I want to get data from another database with another php file according to `rsuserid` and `this.kimeid`. I have also `rsuserid` from my localstorage but I need `kimeid` from my `html` page `item.kimeid`.

Comment: item loaded asynchronously ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask

Comment: I d'ont understand "I want to call function with params `ìtem.kimeid` when item is loading." Explain more please. Can you share the your on code sandbox or stackblitz ?

Comment: when if i have clicked to `<ion-item>` , run fucntion `openmsg()` - i want to run another function `testmsg()` when open the page

Comment: So `testmsg()` is called before `openmsg()` ?

Comment: yes i want to run `testmsg()` before, also `openmsg()` already click event, if i dont click, its not run

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vcpdmb (home page)

Also, look at [Ionic lifecycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)

`ionViewDidLoad()` runs when page is loaded. You can also use `ionViewWillEnter()`. It depends on your application.

Comment: i have checked stackblitz and you dont understand what do i need.
i want run function `testmsg(kimeid)` like this with `ionViewDidLoad()`

Comment: Look at home page

Comment: did you see my comment ?

Comment: I don't understand... What do you want ?

Comment: when i use (click) function , i can take `kimeid` value, how can i take `kimeid` when if i use `ionViewDidLoad()` function ?

Comment: Why you want this id when page is loaded ? You want the first id, the last ? You can get all item id.

Comment: i want that id because i will get data from my database with that kimeid

Comment: OK. So you want create queries with all kimeid and display message related to one id when you click on item. Am I right ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vcpdmb?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts look. Tell me if you want that

Comment: First of all thanks for everything, you are very good man. i will edit my post and i will add my .ts codes, your codes is running without problem but how can i change with my code. please check again my post

Comment: Create a stackblitz project if you want more help

Comment: i tried create a stackblitz project but always taken error :(

Comment: ERROR
Error: this.http
.post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
.map is not a function. (In 'this.http
.post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
.map(function (res) { return res.json(); })', 'this.http
.post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
.map' is undefined)

Comment: Share your stackblitz